# Is "I hope that you are doing well, as well" an acceptable response?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

I would like to reply to a message that says, "I hope you are doing well," and I want to return the acknowledgement. Is it acceptable to reply, "I hope you are doing well, as well?"

Comment: Is this for an employer or a friend/loved one? Response to the message hinges on that in my opinion.

Comment: *Properly*, like "*acceptable*", is primarily opinion-based. Depends on who is involved and exactly what the context is, in detail. No useful answer can be provided for such a question, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

I would say in response:

*Thanks for your good wishes.  I hope you are doing well, too.* (I wouldn't repeat the word "well" as in the original example.)

Answer (score 1):

A very common phrase used to inquire about the wellness of the message recipient is...

> **I hope this message finds you well.**

This phrase behaves like a question, but reads like a statement.

However, according to the article [Speaking Your Reader's Language](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2011/03/speaking-your-readers-language.html) (see paragraph 6 about e-mails to strangers), by Lynn Gaertner-Johnston, you may want to avoid using the phrase when sending a business e-mail. The act of inquiring how a stranger is by using the word *you* (at all) can be considered too *informal*.

[This other article](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2012/07/opening-sentences-for-global-email.html), also by Gaertner-Johnston, explains (see the third-to-last paragraph) how the phrase might have an awkward feeling about it, and gives a list of alternatives. However, I am confident that its use is still OK, as I have seen this being used numerous times even in the past year or two at both work and home.

Finally, [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-hope-this-letter-finds-you-well.74808/) is a sample letter where the phrase is used (see the very first line).

Comment: You say that using the word *you* can be considered too informal.  Is that your personal opinion?  Because it looks like you’re attributing the idea to Lynn Gaertner-Johnston, but I don’t see her saying it.  (Although [her earlier article](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2011/03/speaking-your-readers-language.html "Speaking Your Readers’ Language") questions the conventionality of the phrase “I hope you …”  BTW, did you mean to delete your reference to that article?)  But if it is your personal opinion, how do you reconcile it with “I am confident that its use is still OK”?

Comment: @Scott I work at a business and see colleagues saying it all the time? How do I prove/disprove such a thing? What are you getting at?

Comment: What I'm getting at is (1) you reference Lynn's blog twice, and you sandwich the statement about "considered too informal" between those two references.  This suggests that you're saying that she says that using the word *you* can be considered too informal.  But I don't say her saying it.  If it's just your opinion, you should clarify that.  (2) You say "using the word *you* can be considered too *informal*," but you also say "I am confident that its use is still OK”.  You seem to be contradicting yourself.  So, what is your opinion?

Comment: @Scott I had quite a tough time with the URLs this morning as I am on mobile. Sorry to have caused confusion, there were actually two entirely separate articles! The same article got stuck in the copy/paste queue so I accidentally used it twice!

Answer (score 1):

A simple, "Thank you, I'm well".  But as someone who uses this expression at the start of some emails (only when I know the receiver and we're on more than formal, though less than friendly, terms) I don't actually expect a response.

Comment: I believe that your second sentence contradicts your first one.  You're right; except between the closest of friends, "How are you?" is interpreted as a salutation rather than a question.  "I hope you are doing well" doesn't even *look* like a question (grammatically), so it seems somewhat inappropriate to respond by actually making a statement about your health.  The bottom line is that ReyBoadi's question is about how to respond to the salutation, not how to answer the (implied) inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

You could say, "Thanks; same to you".  They'll get the point.

Comment: If I begin a seventeen-paragraph message "I hope you are doing well," and I get a response several days later that says "Thanks; same to you", I am going to be uncertain as to what that means.